# Cannot flash Moto X Style - Due to "Pre-flash validation failed" error

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, fastboot

I have bricked my device (The Motorola Moto X Style (UK)) after trying to install SuperSU on my device running the latest MM build.

Through hours and hours of research, I am trying to flash a stock build to my device, downloaded from this website https://firmware.center/firmware/Motorola/Moto%20X%20Style/Stock/XT1572/

I am following the instructions in this thread:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-style/development/firmware-moto-x-style-pure-stock-t3272486

These are the commands you are told to enter into command prompt:

```
fastboot oem lock begin
fastboot flash partition gpt.bin
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img
fastboot flash logo logo.bin
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.5
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.6
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.7
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.8
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.9
fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
fastboot erase modemst1 
fastboot erase modemst2 
fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn
fastboot erase cache 
fastboot erase userdata
fastboot oem lock
fastboot reboot
```

I have tried 2 different builds, both of them failing when reaching the same commands.  This is my console window at the moment after reaching the sparsechunk.2 file

```
    D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot devices
TA391006KH      fastboot

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash partition D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\gpt.bin
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:partition: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'partition' (32 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'partition'...
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.393s

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash bootloader D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\bootloader.img
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:bootloader: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (2699 KB)...
OKAY [  0.155s]
writing 'bootloader'...
(bootloader) flashing aboot ...
(bootloader) flashing sbl1 ...
(bootloader) flashing pmic ...
(bootloader) flashing rpm ...
(bootloader) flashing tz ...
(bootloader) flashing hyp ...
(bootloader) flashing sdi ...
OKAY [  1.637s]
finished. total time: 1.805s

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash logo D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\logo.bin
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:logo: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'logo' (3687 KB)...
OKAY [  0.081s]
writing 'logo'...
OKAY [  0.116s]
finished. total time: 0.204s

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash boot D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\boot.img
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:boot: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boot' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.985s]
writing 'boot'...
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 1.702s

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash recovery D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\recovery.img
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:recovery: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (41040 KB)...
OKAY [  0.961s]
writing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 1.728s

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash system D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\system.img_sparsechunk.0
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'system' (257199 KB)...
OKAY [  5.813s]
writing 'system'...
(bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 6.232s

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash system D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\system.img_sparsechunk.1
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'system' (255632 KB)...
OKAY [  5.848s]
writing 'system'...
(bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 5.917s

D:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>fastboot flash system D:\XT1572_CLARK_RETEU_6.0.1_MPHS24.107-58-5_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml\system.img_sparsechunk.2
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'system' (255866 KB)...
OKAY [  5.851s]
writing 'system'...
(bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 5.920s
```

What am I doing wrong?  Do these errors mean that I am trying to flash the wrong firmware?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you get the phone from a retailer, or did it come "branded" by your phone carrier (3, Virgin, or whoever)?

Comment: I bought it 'unbranded', unlocked from any carrier

Comment: OK, that rules out the obvious answer then.

Comment: I have managed to wipe, and do a clean install of Lineage 14.1, so i have a working device again! I'll leave this post up incase someone can come up with a solution

Answer (score 10):

To answer your question specifically: In Moto devices, Preflash Validation Error means the factory image you are attempting to flash is older than the one you have currently installed and Moto devices **do not** support downgrading of the bootloader or partition table (gpt.bin) regardless if the bootloader is locked or unlocked.

There is also a second issue here with the system sparsechunks failing, but that is more related to having other "stuff" in the system folder that is remaining from other ROMs or flashed patches, typically a format (different from a wipe) of /system and /data in TWRP before starting the flash process clears this up.

You are also not beginning or ending your flash process correctly for the image you are using...You should begin with "fastboot oem fb_mode_set" and end with "fastboot oem fb_mode_clear" prior to the reboot, more on this in a second...

There are really 2 options here, you can skip the partition table (gpt.bin), and possibly the bootloader.img file if it fails, and continue the flash process. It should complete and operate normally and you can accept OTA updates. Or you can wait until a newer factory image becomes available.

Performing a "relock" of the bootloader is not possible when downgrading, meaning you got a preflash validation error, because you are not flashing a complete image. Performing an `oem lock begin` and `oem lock` requires ALL pieces of the factory image be flashed successfully, which is not possible if you are downgrading.

To answer the obvious next question, we do not have the latest factory images for this device, we are one to two versions behind depending on the variant, and Moto/Lenovo is less than forthcoming with providing them so we tend to get them by "other" means.

I have written a complete tutorial on XDA on returning this device to it's factory state, it is available [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-style/general/guide-return-to-stock-relock-bootloader-t3489110). All of these issue have been discussed and answered in this thread in great detail, most are recoverable issues but not all without a current factory image.

Comment: +1.By any chance did you make a guide like this for Moto X Play?

Comment: @beeshyams No... X and G, but all recent Moto's are essentially the same process, the specific commands can be derived from flashfile.xml included with each factory image.

Answer (score 1):

find flashfile.bat then run it instead run manual
or you should start to run 2 command:

> fastboot getvar max-sparse-size
>
> fastboot oem fb_mode_set

full example of :

Motorola_Moto_X_Style_XT1572_CLARK_RETLA_DS_7.0_NPHS25.200-15-8_CID12

```
echo off 
fastboot getvar max-sparse-size 
fastboot oem fb_mode_set 
fastboot flash partition gpt.bin 
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img 
fastboot flash logo logo.bin 
fastboot flash boot boot.img 
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.5 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.6 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.7 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.8 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.9 
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.10 
fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin 
fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn 
fastboot flash bluetooth BTFM.bin 
fastboot erase modemst1 
fastboot erase modemst2 
fastboot erase cache 
fastboot erase userdata 
fastboot erase customize 
fastboot erase clogo 
fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn 
fastboot flash bluetooth BTFM.bin 
fastboot oem fb_mode_clear 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
echo please scroll up and check your flash for any errors 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
pause 
fastboot reboot 
exit
```