# Rooting an Android Motorola Moto G4

Tags: root-access, adb

Rooting Motorola Moto G4
I have a Motorola Moto G4 that I would like to root.Quick summary of specs:

- Developer options are enabled

  - OEM unlocking = enabled
  - USB debugging enabled
- Android version: 7.0
- computer os: windows 10
- adb installed

  - `adb devices`: device shows up
  - `adb reboot bootloader` works
- fastboot installed

  - device shows up in `fastboot devices`

Problem: after I go to the bootloader screen and I try `fastboot oem get_unlock_data` the output is:

```
... INFOUnlock data:

INFOUnlock data unavailable

INFOFailed

OKAY [ 0.101s]

finished. total time: 0.101s
```

Tried it also from a linux virtual machine. Same result, no code.

Nothing is added to my path. All commands are run in the installed directories of the programs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: fastboot oem unlock says that an unluck code must be specified. fastboot flashing unlock doesn't exist. MEID is empty.

Comment: i have read somewhere that some OTA break IMEI which result in *Unlock data unavailable* but this is speculation. Another idea is maybe flash unlocked bootloader? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223586/install-twrp-and-magisk-manager-on-moto-g5-plus-without-rooting?noredirect=1#comment289991_223586

Comment: what do you mean with "flash unlocked bootloader"? when I google this, I get  articles about Xaomi.

Answer (score 0):

your device is most likely verizon or AT&T. check your cid is unlockable with

```
fastboot getvar all
```

**Your device is unlockable if the CID value returned is listed**

```
0x0000
0x0003
0x0007
0x0009
0x000B
0x000C
0x000D
0x000E
0x0014
0x0015
0x00DE
0x0032
```

[source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTOROLA-Android-Developer/Bootloader-Unlock-Problems/td-p/3222809)

Comment: cid: 0x0000, so why doesn't it work?