# Can't flash TWRP image on Moto E5+

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp, motorola-moto-e

I try to install a custom ROM on my Motorola Moto E5+. To do that, I'm following this tutorial (and check what is said online on the tools used): https://www.getdroidtips.com/lineage-os-17-motorola-moto-e5-plus/. So I'm at the step where I need to flash the TWRP image, but it seems to don't work.

```
   $ ./adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
ZL5225HPHW  device
   $ ./adb reboot bootloader
   $ sudo ./fastboot flash recovery ../twrp-3.6.0_9-0-hannah.img
(bootloader) is-logical:recovery: not found
Sending 'recovery' (20972 KB)                      OKAY [  0.851s]
Writin 'recovery'                                  (bootloader) Image recovery failed validation
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote: '')
fastboot: error: Command failed
   $ sudo ./fastboot boot ../twrp-3.6.0_9-0-hannah.img
Sending 'boot.img' (20972 KB)                      OKAY [  0.685s]
Booting                                            (bootloader) permission denied!
FAILED (remote: '')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

<sup>[Original screenshot of the terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgCUf.png)</sup>

So I try to use the command: `./fastboot flash recovery ../../Downloads/twrp-3.6.0_9-0-hannah.img` (I'm sudo because it doesn't recognize my phone without) and I try to boot with the image as proposed here: [Can't flash custom TWRP recovery image on Motorola Moto G7 Power phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/211996/cant-flash-custom-twrp-recovery-image-on-motorola-moto-g7-power-phone)
But it doesn't work either. On my phone, it says "Mismatched partition size (recovery)" when I try to flash. And when I try to boot, it just say `download` and `boot` and that it.

Btw, I download the file from here: https://twrp.me/motorola/motorolamotoe5plus.html.

So do you know what I'm missing and what I need to do? Or even if I'm doing it right?

PS: when I'm trying with the official guide of LineageOS, it's doing the same:

```
   $ sudo ./fastboot flash recovery ../lineage-18.1-20220104-recovery-hannah.img
(bootloader) is-logical:recovery: not found
Sending 'recovery' (15432 KB)                      OKAY [  0.666s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 (bootloader) Image recovery failed validation
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote: '')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

And it's say the same on the phone:

```
cmd: download: number
cmd: boot
cmd: getvar:has-slot:recovery
cmd: getvar:max-download-size
cmd: getvar:is-logical:recovery
cmd: download: another number
cmd: flash:recovery
Mismatched partition size (recovery)
```

PS²:
I'm not sure if it's recognize in the good way, since, when I try the command `sudo ./fastboot devices`, it's listed as `ZL5225HPHW Motorola Fastboot Interface`, but I'm not sure that the Motorola Fastboot Interface is good or not?

PS³:
Here are some more commands and the output (I made them under the guidance of @alecxs):
So here is the output:

```
$ sudo fastboot getvar unlocked
(bootloader) unlocked: not found
getvar:unlocked FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.003s
$ sudo fastboot getvar securestate
securestate: oem_locked
finished. total time: 0.009s
```

So, what I'm understanding is that my phone is not unlocked? How I can do that?

Comment: I don't know how accurate the guide on Get Droid Tips is, but there's an official guide for LineageOS on https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hannah/

Comment: Ho, thank @AndrewT. to your edit, I have added the other command that I'm doing before.
And I will check the official guide

Comment: But it doesn't work either, here is my command:
```
   $ sudo ./fastboot flash recovery ../lineage-18.1-20220104-recovery-hannah.img
(bootloader) is-logical:recovery: not found
Sending 'recovery' (15432 KB)                      OKAY [  0.666s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 (bootloader) Image recovery failed validation
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote: '')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```
And it's say the same "Mismatched partition size (recovery)

Comment: I'm a bit curious about the "Preflash validation failed" message. Note that we have [a few questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/176292/44325) related to that message, but I'm not sure if it may help since I don't have experience with Moto devices.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I think I'm quite lost in how it's working. I was thinking I just need the file `lineage-18.1-20220105-recovery-hannah.img` and the image of the OS (like an iso). First of all, I'm not sure what the recovery file? And why "Sam", in the link who send @AndrewT., try to flash so many files???

Comment: And when I do the command `fastboot oem fb_mode_set`, this return `OKAY [  0.002s]
Finished. Total time: 0.002s` in my terminal and `oem fb_node_set` on my phone. So this one seems OK. But, when I'm doing the command `sudo ./fastboot flash recovery ../lineage-18.1-20220104-recovery-hannah.img` after, it's return the same error.

Comment: check output of *'fastboot getvar unlocked'* and *'fastboot getvar securestate'*

Comment: Hello @alecxs good idea to test these command.
So here is the output:
$ `sudo fastboot getvar unlocked`
(bootloader) unlocked: not found
getvar:unlocked FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.003s
$ `sudo fastboot getvar securestate`
securestate: oem_locked
finished. total time: 0.009s

Comment: on your linked tutorial there is a section **Pre-Requirements** - there you will find another link under *"You will require to unlock the device bootloader at first"*

Comment: But, I did that, I have put the key from Motorola to unlock it ?? I will try it again in the next days.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @alecxs, I try again to unlock the device bootloader. And there is it:
➜  ~ fastboot oem unlock **********
(bootloader) WARNING: This command erases all user data.
(bootloader) Please re-run this command to continue.
OKAY [  0.002s]
Finished. Total time: 0.002s
➜  ~ fastboot oem unlock **********
(bootloader) Bootloader is unlocked! Rebooting phone
OKAY [  0.165s]
Finished.

So, I run the command twice and it works, thanks

Comment: please add your last comment to answer, thx

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alecxs, I just don't unlock the device bootloader correctly.

I just need to run the command `fastboot oem unlock ********` twice. And after that, it's working well.

Here the command and the output I have done to resolve the issue

```
➜ ~ fastboot oem unlock **********
(bootloader) WARNING: This command erases all user data.
(bootloader) Please re-run this command to continue.
OKAY [ 0.002s] Finished.
Total time: 0.002s
➜ ~ fastboot oem unlock **********
(bootloader) Bootloader is unlocked! Rebooting phone
OKAY [ 0.165s] Finished.
```

So, I run the command twice, and it works, thanks to all of you in the comments.